# Pan-handle erf in Pretoria

Tags: south-african-english

Can someone provide a synonym for the term "pan-handle erf".  It appears in a legal document from Pretoria, South Africa.  Thanks!

Comment: looks like it's a real estate term: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=panhandle%20erf

Comment: There's already a question about _erf_ here: [Erf as term for plot of land in a town or city. Is this word only used in southern Africa?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/erf-as-term-for-plot-of-land-in-a-town-or-city-is-this-word-only-used-in-southe). _Panhandle_ is a normal English word that can be found in any English dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Explanation of what a *panhandle erf* is: http://www.landsurveyor.co.za/propsub.php. However, as these appears to be a recognised term in SA English, what exactly are you looking for? Any particular version of English? How is your synonym to be used? Please update the question with what you actually need over and above the explanation of what it is.